# Javascript- EventListener("ended"... ) not working

Tags: javascript

idOn a webpage I have a video (the  tag, NOT an iframe), a navigation bar, and a div set to display:none. Through javascript, I am trying to make the video disappear after it ends (the video is set to autoplay="true"), then in its place to display a div (the one I mentioned in the beginning), as well as change the color of some text in the navigation bar. It used to work (when i had it only removing the video, and not the other stuff), and now it seems any code I put after the event listener doesn't work (I tested different parts of the code using alert() to see if it goes off). Here is the code:

```
    var video=document.getElementById('bg');
    video.addEventListener("ended", afterVideo, false);

    function afterVideo() {
        var video=document.getElementById('bg');
        var gallery=document.getElementById('gallery');
        var galleryText=document.getElementById('galleryText');
        var gLink=document.getElementById('gLink');
        video.removeEventListener("ended", afterVideo, false);
        video.style.display='none';
        gallery.style.display='block';
        galleryText.style.display='block';
        gLink.style.color='#0c8acb';
        }
```

I have the code at the top of the code (but after the body tag), however, I saw that doing so was the issue for many people, so I tried it at the bottom, but it didn't work as intended (nor as it used to). The event listener would seem to get triggered early (before the end of the video) and still didn't display the hidden div, nor did it remove the video (but when testing it alert() went off every time).

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="fullVideo">
    <video id="bg" autoplay="true" muted="true">
        <source src="video/main6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/main.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support video.            
    </video>

    <video id="trans1" muted="true" > 
        <source src="video/trans1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/trans1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support video.            
    </video>

    <div id="gallery">
        <div id="galleryText">
            <p>Text goes here!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<nav style="top: 0px;">

    <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="verticalLine"></div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#gallery" id="gLink">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#products" id="pLink">Products</a></li>
            <li class="br"></li>
            <li><a href="#contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="mNav">
        <br style="clear: left;">
        <p>
            <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#products">Products</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </p>
        <hr>
    </div>

</nav>
```

UPDATE: It seems like the event listener gets triggered on page load, runs everything as it's supposed to, but then the video comes back (the one I'm trying to remove), making it look like the code did nothing new...

Comment: Not sure whether it's connected but I believe you have a typo in `var gallery=document.getElementById('galleryText');`. Shouldn't the variable be `galleryText`?

Comment: I just fixed that, but yeah it wasn't the problem.

Comment: Post the relevant part of your HTML.

Comment: There you go. @ PM 77-1

Comment: Where's the element with `'galleryText'` id?

Comment: It is on line 14 inside the "gallery" div. @PM77-1

Comment: There it's a `class` - not an `id`

Comment: Yep my mistake, I just fixed it, but running it again shows no difference, the problem still persists. @PM77-1

Comment: The code you posted runs just fine. Do you have other syntax errors that prevent JavaScript from executing?

Comment: When I run it, it won't work. Could this be caused by incorrect css? As I have tried writing different code using jquery, yet nothing happens after the video ends. I'm using the video as a background(and foreground) to the site, and using different videos that go off when you click each link. Would there be a more efficiant way of doing this without removing and replacing a video? Maybe it being all 1 video and it goes to different parts of it and stops?  @Leo